# EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, console

Eu estou fazendo um programa que é uma resolução dessa [questão da Olimpíada de Informática](https://olimpiada.ic.unicamp.br/pratique/p2/2012/f1/colchao/).

```
A, B, C = input("A").split(), input("B").split(), input("C").split()
A, B, C = int(A[0]), int(B[0]), int(C[0])
if A >= 1 and A <= 300 and B >= 1 and B<= 300 and C >= 1 and C <= 300 : 
    pass
else :
    raise ValueError("Deu Erro")


H, L= int (input("Qual a altura")), int (input("Qual a Largura"))#dimensões da porta
if H >= 1 and H <= 250 and L >= 1 and L <= 250 :
    pass
else:
    raise ValueError("Deu Erro")

if (A and B) > (H and L) or (A and C) > (H and L) or (B and C) > (H and L):
    print ("N")
else :
    print("S")
```

Ele ainda tem muitas falhas, mas ao rodar ele não estou tendo o erro:

> EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Quando coloco pra corrigir ele, estou. Eu queria saber o porquê disso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código está um pouco confuso, e pelo que deu para ler no enunciado não deve pedir 3 entradas e quebrar em partes, deve ler uma entrada e quebrar (odeio isso, costuma dar problemas, mas vamos fazer o que o exercício pede). Depois deve pedir um dado para ser quebrado em duas partes. Curiosamente uma parte do código fez de um jeito e o outro de outro jeito, mas ambos errados de acordo com o demonstrado na página.

Deixei a exceção exposta assim embora isso não é um código bem feito, mas serve como exercício principalmente porque ele não pede para tratar adequadamente, mas tenha isso em mente.

```
entrada = input("A B C").split()
A, B, C = int(entrada[0]), int(entrada[1]), int(entrada[2])
if A >= 1 and A <= 300 and B >= 1 and B <= 300 and C >= 1 and C <= 300:
    pass
else:
    raise ValueError("Deu Erro")
entrada = input("Qual a altura e largura").split()
H, L = int(entrada[0]), int(entrada[1])
if H >= 1 and H <= 250 and L >= 1 and L <= 250:
    pass
else:
    raise ValueError("Deu Erro")
if (A and B) > (H and L) or (A and C) > (H and L) or (B and C) > (H and L):
    print ("N")
else:
    print("S")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/BwEjDh). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vzgyasqq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Console/MatressChoice.py).

Comment: @Smaug eu acebei me perdendo na hora de escrever, editei.

Answer (score 0):

Esta questão que tem como título `Colchão`, foi inicialmente disponibilizada pela [OBI de 2012](https://olimpiada.ic.unicamp.br/pratique/p2/2012/f1/colchao/) e posteriormente, disponibilizada por [Uri Online Judge](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2409), com o mesmo título, `Colchão`, e com a numeração `2409` da categoria `AD-HOC`.

Como é de se perceber, a questão nos pede para verificar se dada as dimensões de um colchão, dizer se o mesmo consegue ou não passar pela porta, com uma de suas `faces`, paralela ao chão.

Observe que a questão diz, que o colchão deve passar pela porta com `uma` de suas faces **paralela** ao `chão`. Além disso, nos diz que as dimensões do colchão são `(1 <= A, B, C <= 300)` e também, as dimensões da porta são `(1 <= H, L <= 250)`.

Para resolver esta questão corretamente devemos perceber que como a dimensão máxima do colchão é `300` e a dimensão máxima da porta é `250` e que também, o colchão sempre passará pela porta com uma de suas faces `paralela` ao chão, devemos implementar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
colchao = sorted(list(map(int, input().split())))
porta = sorted(list(map(int, input().split())))

if (colchao[0] <= porta[0]) and (colchao[1] <= porta[1]):
    print('S')
else:
    print('N')
```

Veja o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/ibcdywoc-solkarped).

Observe que, quando este algoritmo é executado, a tela fica limpa aguardando os valores das `dimensões do colchão`. Neste momento devemos, digitar todas as `três` dimensões do colchão, na `mesma` linha, separadas por `apenas um` espaço e pressionar `Enter`.

Depois que digitamos todas as dimensões do colchão, os valores são `ordenados` e armazenados dentro da lista `colchao`.

Em seguida inserimos as dimensões da `porta` tal como inserimos as do colchão.

Após pressionarmos a tecla `enter` o programa irá verificar se a `menor` dimensão do colchão é menor ou igual à `menor` dimensão da porta e, também, verificará se a `dimensão intermediária` do colchão (largura do colchão) é menor ou igual à `maior` dimensão da porta. Caso o resultado seja positivo, exibirá a mensagem `S`. Caso contrário, exibirá a mensagem `N`.

Esta questão já foi `testada`, `submetida` e devidamente `aprovada` no site `URI` sob a linguagem de programação `Python 3`.

Só para constar, esta questão levou apenas **0.036 s** para ser executada no site do URI.